# Will Python skip over reading an 'else' conditional if the 'if' conditional was already run?

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements, skip

I'm looking at the flow of execution for some of my code, and I'm wondering if the following will work.

Specifically, I am looking at the `else` clause in this conditional tree. If no configuration path is specified in memory, I will get a function that will take the configuration path as input. Let's say I give correct input.  There is no reason for the computer to run the conditional embedded after `declareConfPath()` that checks if anything was specified when `declareConfPath()` was run.

My question is if the program skips over the `else` case, or if it reads the `else` case and will take the new value of `confPath` that was specified by `declareConfPath()` in the first `if` case on the tree. If it does not skip then I have solved all of the conditionals necessary much more sparsely than an alternative solution which would involve another tree. If not, then I need to duplicate a couple of lines of code. That isn't costly but it isn't elegant either.

It could also be the case that using `elif` instead of `if` might get what I want done, but I don't know.

```
confPath = None; # or if the file when opened is empty?
_ec2UserData = None;
localFile = False;

# As we are dealing with user input and I am still experimenting with what information counts for a case, going to use try/except.

# Checks if any configuration file is specified
if confPath == None: #or open(newConfPath) == False:
    # Ask if the user wants to specify a path
    # newConfPath.close(); <- better way to do this?
    confPath = declareConfPath();
    # If no path was specified after asking, default to getting values from the server.
    if confPath == None:
        # Get userData from server and end conditional to parsing.
        _ec2UserData = userData(self);
    # If a new path was specified, attempt to read configuration file
    # Does the flow of execution work such that when the var is changed, it will check the else case?

else confPath != None:
    localFile = True;
    fileUserData = open(confPath);
```

Comment: `else` does not have a condition. Either use `else:` or `elif condition:`.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot use a conditional after `else`, only after `elif`. `elif` is *only* checked if the preceding `if` or `elif` conditionals did *not* match.

Demo:

```
>>> foo = 'bar'
>>> if foo == 'bar':
...     print 'foo-ed the bar'
...     foo = 'baz'
... elif foo == 'baz':
...     print 'uhoh, bazzed the foo'
... 
foo-ed the bar
```

Even though `foo` was set to `baz` in the first block, the `elif` condition did not match.

Quoting from the [`if` statement documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-if-statement):

> It selects **exactly one** of the suites by evaluating the expressions one by one until one is found to be true [...]; then that suite is executed (and **no other part of the `if` statement is executed or evaluated**). If all expressions are false, the suite of the `else` clause, if present, is executed.

Emphasis mine.

In fact, this extends to the *other conditions* too:

```
>>> if True:
...     print "first condition matched"
... elif int("certainly not a number"):
...     print "we won't ever get here, because that's a `ValueError` waiting to happen"
... 
first condition matched
```

Note how the `elif` condition is entirely ignored; if it wasn't, an exception would be raised.